# Creating service bean Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, cloud

So I'm trying to connect my API to cloud to retrieve some credentials.
I've never done API before so I'm new to everything

I'm following some tutorials and all of them have the "Cloud" Bean

```
@Bean
public Cloud cloud() {
  return new CloudFactory().getCloud();
}
```

But it alywas gives an error that its not explained in the tutorials ig or i am just missing it.
It says "It cannot resolve symbol Cloud" and the same for Cloud Factory
Ik here is something very small im missing like adding a dependency but im just lost...

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post at least the complete class with an error. Probably it misses an import or has some syntax error, but we cannot understand it from the given code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing [spring-cloud-spring-service-connector](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector) dependency